# c++ find text in QStringList that starts with "..." using .indexOf

Tags: c++, qt, indexof

I have a question concerning QStringList:

I have a .txt-File containing several 1000 lines of Data followed by this:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------|     
 |  Conditions at          |      X1           |     X2                |     
 +-------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------|     
 |  Time [ms]              |   0.10780E-02     |     0.27636E-02       |     
 |  Travel [m]             |   0.11366E+00     |     0.18796E+01       |     
 |  Velocity [m/s]         |   0.43980E+03     |     0.13920E+04       |     
 |  Acceleration [g]       |   0.11543E+06     |     0.20936E+05       |  
…
```

Where the Header (Conditions at…) and the first column (Travel, Time,…) always stay the same but the values vary for each run. From this File I want to read the values (only!) into fields of a GUI.
First I write all data into a QStringList. (Each line of .txt copied to one Element of QStringList)

To get the values, from the QStringList I tried to find the corresponding lines with “*.indexOf()*" which didn´t work because I have to ask for the exact text of the **whole line**. Since the values vary, the lines are different for each run and my program is not able to find corresponding lines.

Is there a command like “*.indexOf-Starting with certain text*” which would find me the lines **starting** with a certain text for example “|  Time [ms]”

Thank you very much

itelly

Comment: is the | sign followed by spaces? however, you can search for the second and third occurence of "|   "

Comment: use split, read http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is method “.indexOf-Starting with certain text”. You can use regular expressions to match the beggining of a string:

```
 int QStringList::indexOf (const QRegExp& rx, int from = 0) const
```

Use it in this way:

```
int timeLineIndex = stringList.indexOf(QRegExp("^\|  Time \[ms\].+"));
```

`^` means that this text should be at the beggining of a string
`\` escapes special characters
`.+` means that any text can follow this

EDIT:
Here is a working example that show how it works:

```
QStringList stringList;
stringList << "abc 5234 hjd";
stringList << "bnd|gf dfs aaa";
stringList << "das gf dfs aaa";
int index = stringList.indexOf(QRegExp("^bnd\|gf.+"));
qDebug() << index;
```

Output: 1

EDIT:

Here is a function for ezee usage of this:

```
int indexOfLineStartingWith(const QStringList& list, const QString& textToFind)
{
  return list.indexOf(QRegExp("^" + QRegExp::escape(textToFind) + ".+"));
}

int index = indexOfLineStartingWith(stringList, "bnd|gf");  //it's not needed to escape characters here
```

Comment: Thank you, Ezee. I tried this but it gives me the position within the string (=line), not in the stringlist (=.txt)

Comment: Call this method from a string list (`QStringList`) and you'll get a position of a line starting from this text.

Comment: Added an example for you. You can try it.

Comment: Added a function which takes text to find a line which begins with.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Ezee, it works now!! At first he didn´t like "[ms]". So I´m now just searching for "Time" without the [ms] which works fine. itelly

Comment: You're welcome. Try `indexOfLineStartingWith`. It works with [ms] for sure. But pay attention for amount of spaces in the text.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your actual data starts from the line 4 (excluding the header). Second - each data string has specific layout, that you can parse. Assuming that you read the whole file into the QStringList, where each item in the list represents each line, you can do the following:

```
QStringList data;
[..]
for (int i = 3; i < data.size(); i++) {
    const QString &line = data.at(i);

    // Parse the X1 and X2 columns' values
    QString strX1 = line.section('|', 1, 1, QString::SectionSkipEmpty).trimmed();
    QString strX2 = line.section('|', 2, 2, QString::SectionSkipEmpty).trimmed();
}
```

Comment: I was on the way answering... :) but your answer is much more clever!

Comment: Tank you, Vahancho. I thought about something like that, but I would like to avoid to go through the whole file with a loop.

Comment: I would like to do it with .indexOf(). Is there a difference in the way the computer processes a loop and the indexOf-command? ( My QStringList could be several 10 000 lines in size)

Comment: @user3443063 then you can count with your fingers at which position the values appear, but then don't use your computer, print it out and count it, vahancho gave you a good solution for your problem, if you think about performance loss...you should start somewhere else.

Comment: You should use a loop without any doubts. Using `indexOf` will slow down your performance significantly. Hovewer, if a sec or two are not important for you, use can use any way to deal with the data. But if you need performance I also recomment to you not to store all file in `QStringList` but read it line by line and parse it with `split` or `section`. But your question was about `indexOf..starting` and that is why I gave you answer exactly to it.